# Should csrf tokens be included for each request?

Tags: php, csrf

Supose that the users have private content on their account . Like any social websites , when they browse their account , the users can see alot of things about them . Are all of those requests tokenised? Is it a good ideea to make a pattern and tokenise all requests and check them before they are processed ? Any sugestion ?
Do all apps based on private accounts system tokenise all requests?

P.S. : here is a possible attack : the user logs in a social website ("x"), stays loged in , goes to another website ("y") . Website y has a button that gets the first page content of the x site which includes users latest posts . Since the user is loged in , the data will show ...

How would you set up a csrf token mechanism for each request? Set up a middle process that redirects the request to the final processing page if its a valid request? or ... any other ideeas ? Am i wrong here ? Do i see things wrong?

Here i asked same question and got the right final answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10006276/1284817 . The validated answer here is good to read about it too .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSRF tokens are only normally attached to things that change things on the users behalf (e.g. POST requests). Protecting attackers from *viewing* private data is much simpler, and indeed is baked right in to all popular browsers:

To protect attackers *viewing* private data (rather than modifying it) you would usually rely on the browser's [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), and ensuring your requests do not support [Cross-origin resource sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing)

In the specific example of the attack you suggest, the attacker requests example.org/private and the browser will throw an exception which looks like this on my browser:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.org/private. Origin http://attacker.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```